# How can I limit Jenkins LDAP access to users in a specific groupOfNames?

Tags: ldap, hudson, jenkins

I can configure Jenkins so it limits access to users on my ldap server by setting the Server and Root DN without a problem.

Now I want to tie down access a little more and only allow access to members of the groupOfNames cn=MyProject,ou=Group,dc=bogus,dc=biz, but I don't see how to do that in Jenkins.

Can someone explain how they configured Jenkins or Hudson to handle something like this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NOTE: I'm not sure if this would work for LDAP (we use active directory)

- In the project configuration page, check Matrix-based security.
- Remove all access for anonymous
- Add your 'groupOfNames' to the "user/group to add" and give them the rights you want to.

Any user in that group should get the rights you assign. This is how we did it.

Comment: Wow,  Not in a thousand years would I have thought to go poking around in the matrix-based security section.  It looks like this works, but I won't know for sure until next week when I can get someone from outside my group to try to log in.    Note the help for this section looks to be outdated in that I didn't need to add the 'ROLE_' prefix to the group name nor capitalize the group name.

Comment: Yeah, the ROLE_ thing was changed a couple of releases ago for the plugin. Well, let us know if it works!

Comment: Specifically, ROLE_ was removed in release [1.404](http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog#v1.404).

Comment: BTW, now there is great screen on http://your-jenkins:port/whoAmI where you can see what groups you belong to.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! This has helped me after searching in vain for about an hour.

Answer (score 6):

Old thread, I know. I got it working by installing the memberof and refint [overlays](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html) on the OpenLDAP server (2.4.31) and setting the User Search Base on Jenkins to filter the result, i.e.

(&(uid={0})(memberOf=cn=MyGroupName,ou=group,dc=mydomain,dc=com))